# How to map a list of SNPs to genes?

Tags: batch-file, marker, genetics

I have been searching the answer to this question for a while. It seemed like it would not be hard to solve at first, but it seems quite challenging now.

I am searching for a way to submit a list of of SNPs (rs#) and get back a list of the genes these markers map to.

So far I have mostly ways to map SNPs to diseases, pathways, etc. Or to use genes to get a list of representative SNPs.

Also, I am quite new to computational biology, so I would appreciate a solution that doesn't rely heavily on programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.scandb.org

Select "Queries" and then "SNP" from the menu at the top.

Seems to do the job!

Comment: Thank you! I found something else like that as well, just FYI....pfSNP database :)